# candle close above previous high or low

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

CLosing above previos candle high make green bar and closing below previos low make red bar

```
//@version=2

study("High-Low Bar Coloring")

prev_high = high[1]
prev_low = low[1]

green_bar = close > prev_high and close > prev_low
red_bar = close < prev_high and close < prev_low

barcolor(green_bar ? green : (red_bar ? red : na))
```

I dont want to print na
instead it should check previos signal and print that

i want if the candle close above previos high it should continues print green bar till it close previos low

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `var` keyword to "save" the value of a variable:

> Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn’t include the keyword var, results in the value of the variable being overwritten with every update of the data. Contrary to that, when assigning variables with the keyword var, they can “keep the state” despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within if-expressions are met.

I don't believe the `var` keyword exists in version 2, but your script is easily can be upgraded to version 5:

```
//@version=5

indicator("High-Low Bar Coloring", overlay = true)

prev_high = high[1]
prev_low = low[1]

var color colorOfBar = na

if close > prev_high and close > prev_low
    colorOfBar := color.green
if close < prev_high and close < prev_low
    colorOfBar := color.red

barcolor(colorOfBar)
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I tried so much from chatgpt but it's not working... You saved so much of my time Thank you so much

Comment: //@version=5

indicator("High-Low Bar Coloring", overlay = true)

timeFrameTest = input.timeframe(defval = "", title = "Input TF")

prev_high = high[1]
prev_low = low[1]


var color colorOfBar = na

if close > prev_high and close > prev_low
    colorOfBar := color.green
if close < prev_high and close < prev_low
    colorOfBar := color.red

barcolor(colorOfBar)

further how can I use multi time frame in that

Comment: Tap anywhere on the chart (not the pine script window, but rather on the bar chart itself) and then press any number on your keyboard. This will open the "Change interval" popup where you can change the timeframe